# ActiveAndroid select all from class

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I want to make the simplest query but can't find anywhere online how to do it in active android.

I have an Items table that I simply want to get all items for but my query is only returning me one.

```
 items1.name = "item1";
 items2.name = "item2";
 items1.save();
 items2.save();

 List<Item> queryResults = new Select().from(Item.class).execute();
 aToDoAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, (ArrayList<Item>) queryResults);
```

My result list is always whatever the last item I saved was.  How can I get all of the items in the table?

Comment: copy you method compeletly here so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
return new Select()
      .all()
      .from(Item.class)
      .execute();
```

This will return all the items from the Items class.